# How to save a date value in firestore

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore

`type="date"` in html saves as a string in firestore.

In the html file.

```
<input #scheduledStartDate="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="reposition.scheduledStartDate"
name="scheduledStartDate" id="scheduledStartDate" class="input is-normal"
type="date" required placeholder="Leaving...">
```

from the interface .ts file

```
scheduledStartDate?: DateTimeFormat;
```

Also tried

```
scheduledStartDate?: Date;
```

With the same result.

Both options save the inputted date value as a string in firestore e.g. "2018-01-02" instead of a timestamp.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code?

Comment: Did you find the way to do it?

Comment: If you use the Firestore Console to create a document and select `timestamp` as a field type, it will save as a ISO8601 string.  Also, a document's `createTime` and `updateTime` parameters are also stored in this format.  So, unless you have a very specific requirement to store that date as a Linux/Unix timestamp, I'd suggest sticking with your current format.

Answer (score 17):

Before saving the javascript object to firestore, just create an instance of Date() and pass the value like this `new Date("December 10, 1815")`

#### Syntax

```
var docData = {
    stringExample: "Hello world!",
    booleanExample: true,
    numberExample: 3.14159265,
    dateExample: new Date("December 10, 1815"),
    arrayExample: [5, true, "hello"],
    nullExample: null,
    objectExample: {
        a: 5,
        b: {
            nested: "foo"
        }
    }
};
db.collection("data").doc("one").set(docData).then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
})
```

#### Cloud Firestore supports,

> **Date and time**  -  *Chronological* - When stored in Cloud Firestore, precise only to microseconds; any additional precision is rounded down.

#### Note

When a query involves a field with values of mixed types, Cloud Firestore uses a deterministic ordering based on the internal representations.

#### Official Links

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/data-types
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data

Answer (score 4):

You should use the firestore function `firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate` as below

```
const mydoc = {
  name: 'John Doe',
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date("December 10, 1815")) 
}

// save the document 
db.collection("mycollection").doc("id1").set(mydoc).then(function() {
    console.log("Document successfully written!");
});
```