# How to save Date as Timestamp in Angular Firestore?

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, angularfire2

```
firestore.Timestamp.now();
```

I tried this way and it saves date as map.

```
nanoseconds: 388000000
seconds: 1570897877
```

**nanoseconds and seconds type are number.**

I want to save date as firestore timestamp using angular. I found duplicate questions without accepted answer.

- [How to save data as Firestore Timestamp object in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53372270/9006622)
- [How to save date in Angular as a timestamp to Firestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53336061/9006622)
- [How to save a date value in firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48757569/9006622)

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full code that adds data to Firestore (not just a call to a single function).  We should be able to reproduce exactly what you're seeing.  Also consider that using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` is typically what you use to let the server put the current time in a field.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.FieldValue.html#servertimestamp

Answer (score 4):

If you want to add the current time as your Timestamp value in a Firestore document, you can you add it using `FieldValue.serverTimestamp()` as Doug mentioned, as in the following example:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
[ . . . ]
db.collection('times').add({time: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp()});
```

Should you want to get a specific time, you can create a new Date object and add it to your Firestore using the function `toDateString()` on it, as follows:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
[ . . . ]
date = new Date('2018-11-16T09:48:51.137Z'); //sample date
this.db.collection('times').add({spec_time: this.date.toDateString()});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

...


const data = {
    createdAt: firebase.default.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
};
```

This code worked for me.
The important part was `.default` from the root firebase object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`

Import **firebase**

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
```

Initialize it

```
firebase.initializeApp(environment.firebase);
```

then you can use

```
firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP
```

To get the timestamp in milliseconds

Now, If you want to save the timestamp as Date then simply convert the timestamp by moment into your desired format and save it to the database

```
db.object("collection").set(moment(firebase.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP).toDate());
```